# Read Documents and fields from firebase flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore, stream

I have cloud Firestore with one Collection , this collection has many documents and documents have many fields

I use stream to get data from the collection and it was work fine but I add some conditions that make my code complex and I didn't understand how to solve it....

```
if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
        DocumentSnapshot doc = snapshot.data!.docs.map((e) =>
            e.data()) as DocumentSnapshot<Object?>;
        Map<String, dynamic> data = doc as Map<String, dynamic>;
        print(data.toString());
      }
```

I want to know how to read:

1. documents in that collection
2. field in this documents

this my code

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
final auth = Provider.of<AuthBase>(context,listen: false);
return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
  stream: auth.streamStateChanges()
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {

    }
    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {
      

      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
        print(snapshot.data?.docs.map((e) => e.data()));//???????
      }

    }
    return Container();
  });
```

what should I replace this code I want when ConnectionState.done to return a list of (documents , field) from my collection

```
*===> final _database = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('userInfo');
*===> Stream<QuerySnapshot> streamStateChanges() => _database.snapshots();
```

Answer (score 0):

**read field in the specific document**

The document Id of each document must be saved in its field so you can read the specific document data when you get all documents

example:

```
var document = db.collection("collectionName").doc();
var documentId = document.id
document.set({
"documentId":documented,
"otherField": ...,
...,
... })
```

---

for get specific field value

```
db.Collection("collectionName").doc("yourDocumentId").get()
    .then((doc){
print("${doc.get("documentId")}");
});
```

your stream should be like this

```
db.Collection("collectionName").doc("yourDocumentId").snapshots();
```

fore read data like this

```
snapshot.data["documentId"].toString(),
```

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

if your stream is return like this:

```
db.Collection("collectionName").snapshots();
```

it returns a list of documents so to reach for each document you should use it like that

```
switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
   case ConnectionState.none:
     return FutureWidgets.connectionStateNone;
   case ConnectionState.waiting:
     return FutureWidgets.connectionStateWaiting;
   case ConnectionState.active:
     return FutureWidgets.connectionStateActive;
   case ConnectionState.done:
     return ListView(
       padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
       children: snapshot.data!.docs.map((document) {
        if(document['someFieldName'] == "someValue")
         {//Todo:do what you want in this document
                 }
         return Text("${document['fieldName'].toString()}");
       }).toList(),
     );
 }
```

Comment: Bilal Almefleh:

I try with this=>

for (var element in snapshot.data!.docs) {
              print('Document is : ${element.id}');
          }
and get many documents with errors

Comment: see my update ,I describe the most case

Comment: thanks, but got errors:

Comment: Null check operator used on a null value
,,,,,Bad state: field does not exist within the DocumentSnapshotPlatform

Comment: let me see your code now to solve it

Answer (score 0):

```
abstract class AuthBase{

  Stream<QuerySnapshot> streamStateChanges();

}

class Auth implements AuthBase {
  final _firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  final _database = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('userInfo');

  @override
  Stream<QuerySnapshot> streamStateChanges() => _database.snapshots();


}
```

here provider

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final auth = Provider.of<AuthBase>(context,listen: false);
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: auth.streamStateChanges(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {

        switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
          case ConnectionState.none:

          case ConnectionState.waiting:

          case ConnectionState.active:
          
          case ConnectionState.done:
            return ListView(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
              children: snapshot.data!.docs.map((document) {
                if(document['${auth.currentUser?.uid}'] == auth.currentUser?.uid)
                {//Todo:do what you want in this document
                }
                return Text(document['username'].toString());
              }).toList(),
            );
        }

          //return UserNamePage();

        return Container();
      });
  }
```

this home screen